# Json returned from recaptcha is ... bad

Tags: json, recaptcha

When doing 
    `$response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context);`
    `$result   = json_decode($response);`

The response is
    `)]}'` 
    `["uvresp","03AJpayVHarkP_b40i5...stuff...VOrIy6m3ws",1,120]`

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

The `)]}'` breaks things.  I have no idea where that is coming from.
`$g_recaptcha_response` looks fine to me (what I am sending to google to verify).

The function to verify recaptcha

```
function verify_recaptcha ($g_recaptcha_response, $remote_address) {
    # Verify captcha
    $post_data = http_build_query(
        array(
            'secret' => 'secret',
            'response' => $g_recaptcha_response,
            'remoteip' => $remote_address
        )
   );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $post_data
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context);
    $result   = json_decode($response);

    return $result->success;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Actually problem on my end.  Above code works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok my bad. The above code works, I had a problem further downstream (query was trying to use a column that did not exist).